# How To WrapUp the Shell Script with One Line of Command with Argument Passing

Tags: shell, pip, sh, virtualenv, conda

I use lots of virtual environment nowadays since the different project parallely going on in my company.

Following is what I usually do for the initial setting of conda creation of new virtual environment

```
conda install --yes --file requirements.txt
source activate myenv
python -m ipykernel install --user --name myenv --display-name “kernel_name”
```

Upon the above sequence of code must be ran sequentially while `myenv` and `kernel_name` being passed as an manually given argument.

How could I do this at once with wrapped up `.sh` file? or is this possible without creating `.sh` file?

Answer (score 0):

You can do it using a shell script. I would do:

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash
myenv="$1"
kernel_name="$2"
source /path/to/base/conda/installation/etc/profile.d/conda.sh
conda install --yes --file /path/to/requirements.txt
conda activate "$myenv"
python -m ipykernel install --user --name "$myenv" --display-name "$kernel_name"
```

And run it like: `/path/to/script.sh <env-name> <kernel-name>`